# Send notification to another view controller when request finishes

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-blocks

I am working on an Iphone Application (ios5 + storyboard + arc).
I have 2 ViewControllers A and B.

In A I have a button. when pressed I am submitting a request asynchronously to the server (using AFNetworking) and I will go to View Controller B by using performSegueWithIdentifier (push not modal).

When the request finishes it executes a request successful Block that will save data to the database. (The block is in ViewController A since the request is sent from there)

Is there a way I can notify ViewController B that the request has finished and execute a method in B?

What I'm looking for is that when the request finishes and enters the Success Block I run a method in view controller B which is the loaded view.

I hope I was clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For posting a notification use the below code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Midhun" object:nil];
```

In the viewDidLoad of the notification listening class add observer like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performTask:) name:@"Midhun" object:nil];
```

`performTask:` is the method which will be called when the notification is observed.

Please refer [NSNotification Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: By the way I had to write the method without the two point (:) in order to work. it was crashing with them

Comment: Sorry, dude. I forgot to mention. If you are passing any parameter then you need to put that : . It is better to declare the function like `- (void)performTask:(id)sender` :)

Answer (score 1):

First options is to store reference to view controller B somewhere (as example in application delegate) and use it to run a method.

The second one is to send notification via `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`, so controller B set a listener to a notification somewhere (viewDidLoad can be a good place):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(finished:) name:@"requestfinishes" object:nil];
```

and controlle A sends it:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"requestfinishes" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

Note that if you send a notification from a different thread, listener will be executed on the same thread.